# I want to run a jar file from a specific jre from a windows batch file, and want the black window to be closed

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I am trying to run a jar file from a jre in a specific location from a windows .bat file have this as the last line in my batch file

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -jar -Xmx128m -Xms64m -XX:MaxPermSize=64m "%~dp0Myfolder\dist\Myjar.jar" %*
```

I want the black window of the batch file to close after running this jar.
how can i do it

Comment: Would it not make more sense to have the `-jar` option directly preceding the `jar` file?

Comment: how does this help in getting rid of the black window of the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to distribute your .jar file and make it runnable at other people's Windows computers, you can make a simple .bat file like this in the command prompt:

```
java -jar MyJavaTool.jar
```

and place the .bat file in the same directory as your .jar file.

Comment: This is not feasible. And also my jar file is running as it is, it is the command black window of the batch file that I want to get rid of

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the command line with:

```
start %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -jar -Xmx128m -Xms64m -XX:MaxPermSize=64m "%~dp0iStartV5\dist\Myjar.jar" %*
```

solves the problem.

See also [the documantation for `start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html).